# how to create Object key & value in JavaScript dynamically from array string

Tags: javascript, dynamic, javascript-objects

I want to create a JavaScript object dynamically from two arrays of strings. One array is used for the key and another for the value. e.g. it should create **element.name="xyz";**etc

```
 var key=["name","id","surname"];
 var value=[["xyz","01","abc"],["def","02","ghi"]]; 
 var element=new Object();
```

from the above value it should create an object like this:

```
    var element=new Object();
    element.name="xyz";
    element.id="01";
    element.surname="abc";

    var element =new Object();
    element.name="def";
    element.id="02";
    element.surname="ghi";
```

Comment: need more clarification about your needs

Comment: Would *element* be an object or an array of objects?  because your *value* object holds an array of 2 "objects"

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create two objects, or perhaps two objects in an array there.

Comment: @simdrouin its an array of objects

Comment: @Andy i want to pass this object to array later

Comment: `var value=[{"xyz","01","abc"},{"def","02","ghi"}];` is this array of Objects? ..`{"xyz","01","abc"},{"def","02","ghi"}` whats this?

Comment: It's not an object because it doesn't have key/value pairs. It looks like it should be an array but you've used the wrong syntax.

Comment: hey can you all help me with this question also http://stackoverflow.com/q/18584226/2307391

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would go like this :

```
var value=[["xyz","01","abc"],["def","02","ghi"]]; // notice it's an array of array instead of an array of objects

var elements = [];

for (var i = 0; i< value.length; i++) {
    var elem = new Object();
    for (var j=0; j< key.length; j++) {
        elem[key[j]] = value[i][j];
    }
    elements.push(elem);
}
```

Comment: for sanity: `j<key.length && j<value[i].length`

Comment: can you help me to solve this problem also http://stackoverflow.com/q/18584226/2307391

Answer (score 4):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) functions to get your result. Map will flatten out array of arrays, and reduce will create object for each array

```js
const key = ['name', 'id', 'surname']
const values = [
  ['xyz', '01', 'abc'],
  ['def', '02', 'ghi']
]

const result = values.map(row =>
  row.reduce((acc, cur, i) =>
    (acc[key[i]] = cur, acc), {}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answers but avoiding the inner loop:

```
var keys = ["name","id","surname"];
var values = [["xyz","01","abc"],["def","02","ghi"]]; // an array of arrays, not objects

function populateObjects(keys, values) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0, l = values.length; i < l; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[keys[0]] = values[i][0];
    obj[keys[1]] = values[i][1];
    obj[keys[2]] = values[i][2];
    arr.push(obj);
  }
  return arr;   
}

var arr = populateObjects(keys, values);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: However, if there is a new property added to the keys/values objects, you need to modify the populateObjects function

Comment: Fair point. Question didn't mention that tho. It indicated the objects would be static.

Answer (score 0):

***Create dynamic object using this***

```
    let featureConfigsData: any = {};
    // let featureConfigsData = new Object();

    if (feature_configs) {
      feature_configs.map((item: any, index: number) => {
        featureConfigsData["" + item.name + ""] = item.value;
      });
      console.log("K_____  ", featureConfigsData);
    }
```